# How to get a count of record number in the same SQL sentence when we are inserting a data into a file in SQLRPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Recently in an interview I was asked , How to get the data count when inserting data into the file using an INSERT statement , I told we can use a Count statement later on to get the count , but he insisted can we get the count while executing the insert statement.
I would really like to know can we get the data count when executing the insert statement in SQLRPGLE if yes then I would really like to know the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options.

1. [SQL Communications area](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=reference-sqlca-sql-communication-area)

> SQLERRD(3)
>
> For a CONNECT for status statement, SQLERRD(3) contains information
> about the connection status. See CONNECT (type 2) for more
> information. For INSERT, MERGE, UPDATE, REFRESH, and DELETE, shows the
> number of rows affected.
>
> For a TRUNCATE statement, the value will be -1.
>
> For a FETCH statement, SQLERRD(3) contains the number of rows fetched.
>
> For the PREPARE statement, contains the estimated number of rows
> selected. If the number of rows is greater than 2 147 483 647, then 2
> 147 483 647 is returned.

usage

```
exec SQL insert ...;
recCnt = sqlErrD(3);
```

2. [GET DIAGNOSTICS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-get-diagnostics) statement

> ROW_COUNT
>
> Identifies the number of rows associated with the previous
> SQL statement that was executed. If the previous SQL statement is a
> DELETE, INSERT, REFRESH, or UPDATE statement, ROW_COUNT identifies the
> number of rows deleted, inserted, or updated by that statement,
> excluding rows affected by either triggers or referential integrity
> constraints. If the previous SQL statement is a MERGE statement,
> ROW_COUNT identifies the total number of rows deleted, inserted, and
> updated by that statement, excluding rows affected by either triggers
> or referential integrity constraints. If the previous SQL statement is
> a multiple-row-fetch, ROW_COUNT identifies the number of rows fetched.
> Otherwise, the value zero is returned.

usage

```
exec SQL insert ...;
exec SQL GET DIAGNOSTICS :recCnt = ROW_COUNT;
```

Comment: Both of these are AFTER the INSERT.  Separate operations.  I think the interviewer was mistaken or perhaps had some agenda around dealing with the impossible... or maybe it was a knowledge test.